# Attributes is missing (grape API)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm newbie in Rails. I tried to write a small API Rails application use `gem grape`.

I followed up this tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/build-great-apis-grape/

But when i tried to create a new record, i had an error as:
`{"error":"type_id is missing"}`

Here is my code:

`singers.rb`

```
module V1
 class Singers < Grape::API
  resource :singers do
    desc "List all singers"
    get do
      Singer.all
    end

    desc "Create a new singer"
    params do
      requires :name, type: String
      requires :type_id, type: Integer
    end

    post do
      Singer.create!({
       name: params[:name],
       type_id: params[:type_id]
      })
    end
  end
 end
end
```

And when i type in console as:
`curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/singers.json -d "name=khanhpn;type_id=1"`

I had an error: `{"error":"type_id is missing"}`

I didn't understand why it throw error. Hope everybody can explain for me. Thank you very much.

This is my code which i pushed on bitbucket:
https://bitbucket.org/baran19901990/grape_api/src/b8a0d676f17de3fedc95cc7efff60fab5afb0fc1/app/api/v1/singers.rb?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Solutions:

`curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/singers -d "name=khanhpn&type_id=1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in passing your parameters to `curl`. You have to separate them by `&` and not `;`
`curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/singers.json -d "name=khanhpn&type_id=1"`

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is not the code, but the curl call...

Try with something like:

```
curl -F name=khanhpn \
-F type_id=1 \
-X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/singers
```

If you want to use -d option, or using a one line command, it would be something like:

```
curl -d "name=khanhpn" -d "type_id=1" -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/singers
```

Comment: I think we didn't need to add POST in `curl`. And we can rewrite as:
`curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/singers -d "name=khanhpn&type_id=1"`

I think it was shorter. But thanks for your answer.